# How to Resolve ILogger in Autofac container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am trying to replace dryIOC container with autofac container for some reason but I don't know the exact syntax how could I resolve ILogger uisng autofac

Here is how I register ILogger in DryIoc

```cs
public void Load(IContainer container)
{
    container.Register<ILoggerFactory, Log4NetLoggerFactory>();
    
    ConfigureLogger(container);
}

[Localizable(false)]
private void ConfigureLogger(IContainer container)
{
    container.Register<ILogger>(
        made: Made.Of(
            r => typeof(ILoggerFactory).GetMethod(nameof(ILoggerFactory.Create), new[] {          typeof(Type) }),
            factoryInfo: ServiceInfo.Of<ILoggerFactory>(),
            parameters: Parameters.Of.Name("type", r => r.Parent?.ImplementationType ?? typeof(Startup))),
        reuse: Reuse.Transient);
}
```

I have tried something like this, but it does not work with Autofac

`container.Register<ILoggerFactory, Log4NetLoggerFactory>();`

Comment: Which nuget package contains the `Log4NetLoggerFactory` type? Is it an implementation of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` interface? Is the `ILogger` interface the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to resolve an instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` then you have two options:

## Option #1 - Resolve a `ILogger<TCategoryName>`.

```cs
public class Something
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Something(ILogger<Something> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

## Option #2 - Resolve an `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<TCategoryName>` automatically.

My nuget package does exactly this using Autofac:
[EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac)

It contains an Autofac module. Register it then magic will happen.

```cs
public class Something
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Something(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger; // It will be an instance of ILogger<Something>.
    }
}
```